# What is the difference between prints in python

Tags: python

What is the difference between prints in python:

```
print 'smth'
print('smth')
```

Comment: No real difference, the first is sort of a syntactical sugar.

Comment: @gravetii: no, the second only works coincidentally, most of the time, in Python 2, where `print` is a statement, not a function. The first isn't syntactic sugar at all, it's the correct usage.

Answer (score 7):

`print` is made a function in python 3 (whereas before it was a statement), so your first line is python2 style, the latter is python3 style.

to be specific, in python2, printing with `()` intends to print a tuple:

```
In [1414]: print 'hello', 'kitty'
hello kitty

In [1415]: print ('hello', 'kitty')
('hello', 'kitty')

In [1416]: print ('hello') #equals: print 'hello', 
                           #since "()" doesn't make a tuple, the commas "," do
hello
```

in python3, print without `()` gives a SyntaxError:

```
In [1]: print ('hello', 'kitty')
hello kitty

In [2]: print 'hello', 'kitty'
  File "<ipython-input-2-d771e9da61eb>", line 1
    print 'hello', 'kitty'
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `print('smth')` in python2 will work though. As `('smth')` is equivalent of writing `'smth'`.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix it's not. `('smth')` is still string, but `('smth',)` is tuple.

Comment: @J0HN that's what I said

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix or maybe you saw my comment after updating yours.  Race condition :)

Comment: To be extra confusing, `()` don't make the tuple, the commas do. Except that the syntax of the `print` statement makes the comma do something else, and the `()` make them make a tuple again.

Comment: @Wooble yes, but you wouldn't want to have `((3 + 4) + 4)`, as `tuple(tuple(3 + 4) + 4)` unless you can propose a new type of bracket that isn't already used.

Comment: @J0HN something like that I guess.

Answer (score 4):

In python 3, [print](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print) is a function.

```
>>> print('a','b','c')
a b c
```

In Python 2, [print](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt) is a keyword with more limited functionality:

```
>>> print 'a','b','c' 
a b c
```

While `print()` works in Python 2, it is not doing what you may think. It is printing a tuple if there is more than one element:

```
>>> print('a','b','c')
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

For the limited case of a one element parenthesis expression, the parenthesis are removed:

```
>>> print((((('hello')))))
hello
```

But this is just the action of the Python expression parser, not the action of print:

```
>>> ((((('hello')))))
'hello'
```

If it is a tuple, a tuple is printed:

```
>>> print((((('hello',)))))
('hello',)
```

You can get the Python 3 print function in Python 2 by importing it:

```
>>> print('a','b','c')
('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print('a','b','c')
a b c
```

[PEP 3105](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/) discusses the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parenthesis in Python 2 and 3 `print`, but they are a must in Python 3.

Python 2:

```
print "Hello"
```

or:

```
print("Hello")
```

Whereas in Python 3:

```
print "Hello"
```

Gets you this:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "Hello"
                ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

So you need to do:

```
print("Hello")
```

The thing is, in Python 2, `print` is a statement, but in Python 3, it's a function.