# Python2: Difference between print and print() with '\r' escape character

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

I am reading a data frame sent by a hardware device that separates each field of the frame with the character `'\r'`. When printing the frame in python 2, I have found differences between `print` and `print()` and some problems with disappearing characters.

Some differences between `print()` and `print` can be found in: 
[What is the difference between print and print() in python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996749/what-is-the-difference-between-print-and-print-in-python-2-7) 
but that not explains the problems that I'm having.

For example, when executing

```
>>>frame = 'word_1#\rword_2\r'
>>>print(frame)
word_2#
>>>print frame
word_2#
```

They are both the same, but I don't understand why the '#' is moved to the end of 'word_2' and why 'word_1' disappears.

Also, `print` and `print()` show different results in:

```
>>>frame = 'word_1#\rword_2\r'
>>>print('data:', frame)
('data', 'word_1#\rword_2\r')  
>>>print 'data:', frame
word_2word_1#
```

Here `print()` seems to work as expected, but `print` has removed `'data'` word and has changed the order of the words.

Finally, it is also confusing this case:

```
>>> frame = 'word_1\r#word2\r#'
>>> print(frame)
#word2
>>> print frame
#word2
>>> print('data', frame)
('data', 'word_1\r#word2\r#')
>>> print 'data', frame
#word2ord_1
```

where `print()`, `print` and `print('data', frame)` seems to work the same way that they did in the previous cases but `print 'data', frame` has removed the initial `'w'` from `word_1` after changing the order.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '\r' character is called carriage return. Its goal is to put the cursor on the beginning of the line.

I will re-wrote you code to explain better what it does : (| is your cursor)

```py
>>> frame = 'word_1\r#word2\r#'
>>> print(frame)
word_1|                            # write word_1
|word_1                            # put cursor on the beginning of the line
#word2|                            # write #word2 but on top of word_1 since your cursor was at the beginning of the line
|#word2                            # put cursor on the beginning of the line
#|word2                            # rewrite the # on top of the previous one

>>> print frame                    # Same things happens here
#word2
```

```
>>> print('data', frame)
('data', 'word_1\r#word2\r#')      # As pointer by U10-Forward this is printing an actual tuple
```

```
>>> print 'data', frame
data|                              # you write data
dataword_1|                        # you write word_1
|dataword_1                        # you put the cursor on the beginning of the line
#word2ord_1|                       # you write #word2 on top of the previous print
|#word2ord_1                       # cursor on the beginning of the line
#|word2ord_1                       # you write again the #
```

BTW: Use Python3 unless you are required to use Python2

Comment: Thanks a for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

> They are both the same, but I don't understand why the '#' is moved to the end of 'word_2' and why 'word_1' disappears.

`\r` is carriage return which means it will move the print pointer to the starting of the line and then start overwriting the output following the `\r`.

So in your case as the no of characters in `word_2` is same as that of `word_1` so after the first `\r` it overwrites `word_1` to produce the output as `word_2#`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This also explains the 3rd case

Answer (score 0):

Because in Python 2:

```
print(...)
```

Is processing a regular `print ...` but just simply printing a tuple, while the other isn't.

Comment: this does not explain why characters disappear or move their position